# How to query for event conflicts using calendarView?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use the [calendarView API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0) to retrieve any possible event conflicts in a date range.

The problem I'm noticing is that it won't return events that:

- Started before the `startDateTime`, and end on or before the `endDateTime`.
- Started on or after the `startDateTime`, and end after the `endDateTime`.
- Started before the `startDateTime`, and end after the `endDateTime`.

Previously, with the [events API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0) I was able to user `$filter`.  I had to move away from this API because it didn't return recurring events.  The calendarView API throws an error when I try to `$filter` these date fields.

```
(start/dateTime ge '${startDate}' and start/dateTime lt '${endDate}')
or
(end/dateTime gt '${startDate}' and end/dateTime le '${endDate}') 
or
(start/dateTime lt '${startDate}' and end/dateTime gt '${endDate}')
```

What's the ideal way to accomplish this? Should I be using a completely different API?

Comment: This was similar with EWS calendar view. I feel it's a mistake in the design and it should return in progress events in that date range, not just events that started/ended within the date range. A benefit of calendar view though is it expands recurring meetings into occurrences, but the same problem applies with the range.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use either [`/findMeetingTimes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findmeetingtimes?view=graph-rest-1.0) or [`/getSchedule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-getschedule?view=graph-rest-1.0) for this.